# Laravel, MariaDB timestamp column without default and onupdate trigger

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration, blueprint

I have following migration:

```php
Schema::create('auctions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamp('expired_at');
    $table->timestamp('sold_at')->nullable()->default(null);
    // other fields
});
```

Which creates a table with this structure:
[image]

Every time I try to update `sold_at` field only, It changes the `expire_at` field also, which is so annoying and against my project's logic! How should I fix my **migration** to prevent this?

My update record code:

```php
Auction::query()->where('id',1)->update([
    'sold_at' => now()
]);
```

Comment: Make it a `dateTime()` column? Make it `->nullable()->default(null)` like the `sold_at` column?

Comment: It works!!!! Thanks ! post it as an answer so I can accept! @brombeer
I dont want to make it `nullable` but `dateTime()` is good for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your column to a `datetime` column:

```
Schema::create('auctions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->dateTime('expired_at');
    $table->timestamp('sold_at')->nullable()->default(null);
    // other fields
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-dateTime

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi:Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable